File upload in GraphqQL
Our project is a program with microservices architecture in Nestjs (we use TCP to communicate between microservices).
We have several different microservices in this project, two of which are Gateway and upload.
Our Gateway is responsible for providing our API Gateway service uses grapqhql to provide API (Apollo server) and our upload service is responsible for managing files.
The problem we have now is how to receive a file in graphql and send it to the upload service.
We tried graphql-upload and several other packages related to this task, but the latest version of these packages does not work properly in typescript.
What are the best solutions in this field and what is your suggestion?

Please include your code that doesn't work so that people have something to go on.
